# Is there a way to erase a column to perform TSNE?

Tags: python

I am doing a classification for IMDb and Youtube movie trailer using KNN.
Because it has numerous dimensions, I decided to use the TSNE.
However, an error keeps appearing , saying : could not convert string to float: 'Avatar'

This is my code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
model = TSNE(learning_rate=100)
transformed = model.fit_transform(df2)

xs = transformed[:,0]
ys = transformed[:,1]
plt.scatter(xs,ys,c=labels)
```

I believe I should simply delete the "movie_title" column, so that I am left with only numerical data for TSNE. Is there a way to remove a particular column in a dataset?

my columns for the dataset are: `movie_title`, `genres`, `country`, `range`,
    `gross`, `budget`, `imdb_score`, `views`, `rating`.

I have tried- table.Columns.Remove("movie_title"), but this doesn't seem to work...

thank you for reading!

Comment: Your dataset is what? An array? A list? A dataframe?

Comment: Thanks! It is a dataframe that I imported from my excel onto colab. I now want to show as TSNE.

Comment: Ok. That helps me get an idea of what can be done. See my answer.

Comment: Thank you! It seems like I am unable to follow.. I tried df2.drop('movie_title', axis=1, inplace=True) and got an error: "['movie_title'] not found in axis" ...

Comment: Do you have a column named `movie_title`? From your post it seemed like it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`df.drop()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html). If your `DataFrame` is named `table`, use this:

```
table.drop('movie_title', axis=1, inplace=True)
```